# Is there appropiate way that each object is generated with a new name

Tags: c#-4.0

```
using System;

namespace rummykhan
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Test t1 = new Test();
            }
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public int first;
        public int second;
    }
}
```

im trying to make 100 objects but i wish these objects are named automatically using some random string. im unable to figure out.. thanx for help in advance..

**EDIT**

Looking at my own question after a year, actually i was looking for a way by which i was able to create object by my own chosen name. e.g.

```
string tmp = "obj1";
var tmp = new Foo();
```

i was thinking that someway obj1 value may kick in and i could call my variable using obj1, which is totally moronic.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the objects in a List.

example:

```
List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tests.Add(new Test());
    }
```

Comment: brother thix ix not my question.. i need to set the object name randomly.. i know how to generate the list of the objects..

Answer (score 0):

write like this.

```
Test[] dynamic = new Test[100];
for (int i=0; i< 100; i++)
{
    dynamic[i] = new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code will  destroy t1 after each iteration of the loop. you could do something like this to preserve 100 coppies of test in memory

```
using System;

namespace rummykhan
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Test> lstClasses = new List<Test>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            lstClasses.Add(new Test());
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    public int first;
    public int second;
}
```

}

Comment: bro i know List implementation.. my question ix can i set the name of the object randomly..

Comment: Is there any reason why you need different names for the variables?